# How to get $_FILES in PHP to access file posted from ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm posting an image from an ASP.NET page to PHP server side $_FILES array.

How can I get the $_FILES array in PHP to access the file posted from ASP.NET?

Comment: how are you calling `PHP server side` from asp.net, C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same regardless of whether your upload form is created with ASP.NET, PHP or any other server-side technology, so long as it renders a correct upload form that posts the file your PHP page, e.g.

```
<form action="UploadHandler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
</form>
```